# How to show count of series in SSRS legend

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, legend, legend-properties

I have a bar chart generated using SSRS, which has 3 series of data in it like
1. New
2. Delivered
3. backlog
I would like to show the count of all the series parts in the legend.

Example :

New (70)
Delivered (50)
Backlog(20)

I would also like to show the percentage in the legend itself like

New (70) 50%

please help me withe properties to do it.

I'm using VS 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write expression to get Label in series like

```
=Fields!Series.Value & " " & Sum(Fields!DATA.Value, "Chart1_SeriesGroup1")
```

Here 'Chart1_SeriesGroup1' is chart series group name

[image]

Similarly, we can do for percentage...